# Spring: endpoint to start a scheduled task

Tags: spring-boot

I have a scheduled task that works perfectly, like this:

```
@Scheduled(cron="*/5 * * * * MON-FRI")
public void doSomething() {
    // something that should execute on weekdays only
}
```

I want to create a REST endpoint that would start this task out of it's normal schedule.

How would I programatically fire-and-forget this task?

Comment: Create a controller and call the method. If you want to run this in the background you can add an additional `@Async`.

Comment: I would want to prevent spring from double-executing it if it detects a schedule.

Comment: That would require quite some logic and wasn't really part of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something really simple.

Your schedule:

```java
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MySchedule {

  private final MyClassThatHasTheProcessing process;

  @Scheduled(cron = "*/5 * * * * MON-FRI")
  public void doSomething() {
    // the actual process is made by the method doHeavyProcessing
    process.doHeavyProcessing();
  }

}
```

Your Controller

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/task")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyController {

  private final MyClassThatHasTheProcessing process;
  // the executor used to asynchronously execute the task
  private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

  @PostMapping
  public ResponseEntity<Object> handleRequestOfStartTask() {
    // send the Runnable (implemented using lambda) for the ExecutorService to do the async execution
    executor.execute(() - >{
      process.doHeavyProcessing();
    });

    // the return happens before process.doHeavyProcessing() is completed.
    return ResponseEntity.accepted().build();
  }

}
```

This will keep your scheduled task working as well as being able do trigger the task on demand by hitting your endpoint.

The `HTTP 202 Accepted` will be returned and the actual thread released, while the `ExecutorService` will delegate the `process.doHeavyProcessing` execution to another thread, which means that it will run in a 'fire and forget' style, because the thread that is serving the request will return even before the other task is finally terminated.

If you don't know what is an `ExecutorService`, [this](https://www.baeldung.com/java-executor-service-tutorial) may help.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by writing something like below

```
 @Controller
    MyController {
    
    @Autowired
    MyService myService;
    
     @GetMapping(value = "/fire")
     @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
        public String fire() {
            myService.fire();
            return "Done!!";
        }
   }
      
 MyService {
    
@Async
@Scheduled(cron="*/5 * * * * MON-FRI")
public void fire(){
    // your logic here
    
 }
}
```